# ufw failed to be initialized

Tags: firewall, docker, root, ufw

I just make a fresh Docker container. But, when I try to enable ufw, I get the following error message:

```
# ufw enable
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ftp not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_nat_ftp not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_netbios_ns not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic
iptables-restore: line 6 failed
iptables-restore: line 22 failed
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Couldn't load match `conntrack':No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 2
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore: line 4 failed
iptables-restore: line 5 failed
iptables-restore: line 21 failed
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"
Error occurred at line: 19
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore: line 10 failed
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"
Error occurred at line: 21
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Chain 'ufw-before-input' does not exist
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians": Read-only file system

Problem loading ipv6 (skipping)
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/after.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules
```

Otherwise, it seams probably related to a root misdetection. Some ufw commands don’t detect the user as root when however it’s him:

```
# ufw allow 22                         
WARN: initcaps                                                                   
[Errno 2] iptables: Permission denied (you must be root).                              
                                                                          
Rules updated                                                                                                                             
Rules updated (v6)
```

So, what to do to be able to use `ufw`?

Comment: Are you trying to run a firewall inside the container?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes.

Comment: But ... why? You only expose the ports you desire to the outside network. What use is a firewall inside the container?